# Implementing The Blue Dot in google Maps

Tags: android

I am building an Android Application related to indoor localization.

I need to create a dot or marker that moves continously and smoothly instead of moving discretely like jumping from one point to another.

Please provide me with an algorithm, since I have tried a lot and can't get any one working as wished.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

1. You have to find a way how to make a marker Visible and Gone with animation.
2. You have to make a array that contains longitude and latitude of a number of point which if you join these points together you will form a line from point A to point B in map your map.
3. You have to make a loop that for each couple of coordinates does a transition ex. for point X and Z it does this:  1) it starts animating point X as "gone" 2) at the same time it starts animating "visible" point Z
4. You have to determine the time for each animation, you can simply choose N-seconds ad default for each animation and divide it with the number of points that you have.

You can determine the number of points between your real A and B point in proportion of your map zoom.

Maybe this is the hardest answer but that is all i can help you

Comment: Thanks, but if you can explain with code that will be much appreciated